# How to intercept GET request in api before execution in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, handler, interceptor

I'm trying to figure out how to intercept a GET call before execution occurs in .NET framework.

I've created 2 applications: a front-end(calls the API and sends custom HTTP headers with it) and a back-end API:

**Front-end method which calls API:**

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> getCall()
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:54857/";
        string customerApi = "2";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //get logged in userID
            HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            string sessionID = context.Session["userID"].ToString();

            //Create request and add headers
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Custom header
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("loggedInUser", sessionID);

            //Response
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(customerApi);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsondata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return Content(jsondata, "application/json");
            }
            return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

**Back-end which receives the request:**

```
public class RedirectController : ApiController
{
    //Retrieve entire DB
    ConcurrentDBEntities dbProducts = new ConcurrentDBEntities();

    //Get all data by customerID
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("{id}")]
    public Customer getById(int id = -1)
    {
        //Headers uitlezen
        /*var re = Request;
        var headers = re.Headers;

        if (headers.Contains("loggedInUser"))
        {
            string token = headers.GetValues("loggedInUser").First();
        }*/

        Customer t = dbProducts.Customers
            .Where(h => h.customerID == id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        return t;
    }
}
```

**Routing:**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

The code shown above works fine, I'm getting the correct results of my API call but I'm looking for a way to intercept **all of the incoming GET request** before im returning a response so i can modify and add logic to this controller. While making my GET request i add custom headers, I'm looking for a way to extract these from the incoming GET all before execution occurs.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you specify if you're using .NET Framework or .NET Core? The pipelines of the two are different.

Comment: @HansKilianm I've added it in the question, its .NET framework.

Comment: You're looking for ActionFilters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ActionFilterAttribute`, used as in the following example, I created the attribute and put it on the api base class where all api classes inherit from, `OnActionExecuting` is entered before reaching the api method. we can check there if the `RequestMethod` is of `"GET"` and do whatever you are planning to do there.

```
public class TestActionFilterAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.Method.Method == "GET")
        {
            //do stuff for all get requests
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}

[TestActionFilter] // this will be for EVERY inheriting api controller 
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{

}

[TestActionFilter] // this will be for EVERY api method
public class PersonController: BaseApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [TestActionFilter] // this will be for just this one method
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAll()
    {
        //normal api stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, so you implement BaseApiController in the API which make calls the backend API? I dont want to make adjustments in that API. There are 2 API's, API-a and API-b, API-a makes a call to API-b, API-b responds and sends data to API-a. When API-a makes this call and API-b receives this call I want to intercept the incoming call of API-a in API-b. So if I'm wrong correct me, but I think all the code to intercept this call should happend in API-b so I can extract the header of the call API-a makes and i can add logic to send the correct reponse back.

Comment: You can just as easily put the `TestActionFilterAttibute` on any of your API-a or API-b, wherever you'd like for it to be needed. even on the api call itself, I'll update my answer